# Angular - Refactoring observables after initiating a resolver

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-observables

I made a Resolver, and my code is working really fine. But i wonder if there is any way to make a refacto in my TS component, since i now get the data from my resolver, but anytime i try to erase a few things i think useless now, my app brokes.
Here is my resolver :

```
@Injectable()
export class MatchTableListResolver implements Resolve<MatchTable[]> {
    constructor(private readonly matchTablesService: MatchTablesService
                ) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<MatchTable[]> {
        console.log("inside resolver")
        return this.matchTablesService.list().map(data => {
            console.log("tata", data); return data});

    }
}
```

and what i would like to refacto in my component.TS file :

```
this.urlWatcher$ = this.route.data.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        withLatestFrom(this.matchTables$),
        map(([params, newMatchTables]) => {
            this.page = 1;
            this.startIndex = 0;
            this.endIndex = 50;

        const matchTableFromParam = newMatchTables.find(m => m.technicalName === params['id']);
        if (matchTableFromParam) {
            this.matchTableSelected = matchTableFromParam;
            this.selectLines(this.startIndex, this.endIndex);
        } else {
            if(newMatchTables.length > 0) {
                this.matchTableSelected = newMatchTables[0];
                this.router.navigate(['/configuration/matchtables/' + this.matchTableSelected.technicalName]);
                this.selectLines(this.startIndex, this.endIndex);
            }
        }
    })
);

this.matchTableList$ = this.matchTablesService.list().pipe(
    map(matchTables => {
        matchTables = matchTables.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === b.name.toLocaleLowerCase() ? 0 : a.name.toLocaleLowerCase() < b.name.toLocaleLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
        this.matchTables$.next(matchTables);
    }),
    catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.loadingError$.next(true);
        return EMPTY;
    })
);

concat(this.matchTableList$, this.urlWatcher$).subscribe();
```

Because i am now using :

```
this.listMatchTable = this.route.snapshot.data.listMatchTable;
```

I am not to used with resolver, but i guess that now i received data from it, i should be able to make things a bit different (maybe get rid of the observables?), but i dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data and params from route using snapshot field

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
this.listMatchTable = this.route.snapshot.data.listMatchTable;
```

Then you can implement your logic without observables

```
this.page = 1;
this.startIndex = 0;
this.endIndex = 50;

const matchTableFromParam = this.listMatchTable.find(m => m.technicalName === this.id);
 if (matchTableFromParam) {
   this.matchTableSelected = matchTableFromParam;
   this.selectLines(this.startIndex, this.endIndex);
 } else {
   if(newMatchTables.length > 0) {
     this.matchTableSelected = this.listMatchTable[0];
     this.router.navigate(['/configuration/matchtables/' + this.matchTableSelected.technicalName]);
     this.selectLines(this.startIndex, this.endIndex);
   }
 }
```